# Can a trigger procedure in PostgreSQL learn its own name?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.4

A [trigger procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) in PostgreSQL can learn the name of the trigger that fired it from the special variable `TG_NAME`. But can it also learn its own name?

I would like to keep additional configuration information that applies per trigger procedure in a new table and need the trigger procedures's name (preferrably not retyped manually) to select values from that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query [`pg_trigger` catalog table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-trigger.html) and gather this information:

```
SELECT
    tg.tgfoid::regproc::text
INTO
    v_function_name
FROM
    pg_trigger tg
WHERE
    tg.tgrelid = TG_RELID
    AND tg.tgname = TG_NAME;
```

`v_function_name` is a variable you must declare before (as text or varchar).

Casting to `regproc` and then to `text` will make it double quote the name if not simple (just like `quote_ident`), if you want to avoid it, you can simple join `pg_proc` and get `proname` (in this case `v_function_name` can be of type `name`):

```
SELECT
    pr.proname
INTO
    v_function_name
FROM
    pg_trigger tg
    INNER JOIN pg_proc pr ON pr.oid = tg.tgfoid
WHERE
    tg.tgrelid = TG_RELID
    AND tg.tgname = TG_NAME;
```